# Derive indirect utility function - Problem with CES

Tags: microeconomics, utility

Consider the following CES utility function for the $h$ household
\begin{equation}
U^h(x^h_1,\ldots,x^h_N) = \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{N} (x^h_j - \zeta^h_j)^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}} \right]^{\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-1}}
\end{equation}
where $\sigma \in (0,\infty)$ denotes the elasticity of substitution and $\zeta^h_j \in [-\bar{\zeta}, \bar{\zeta}]$ denotes whether the particular good is a necessity or not for the household. For example, $\zeta^h_j >0$ may mean that
household h needs to consume at least a certain amount of good $j$ to survive.

It is assumed that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_j \bar{\zeta} < w^h
\end{equation}
where $w^h$ denotes the household $w^h$ income.

Now, to derive the indirect utility function, that according to the book reads
\begin{equation}
\nu^h(p,w^h)= \frac{\left[- \sum_{j=1}^{N} p_j \zeta^h_j + w^h \right]}{\left[\sum_{j=1}^{N} p^{1-\sigma}_j \right]^{\frac{1}{1-\sigma}}}
\end{equation}

I should find the optimal consumption bundles and then plug them into the utility function. I proceeded as follows

Considering two commodities $x^h_j$ and $x^h_{j'}$ with $j \ne j'$:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_j} \Bigg/ \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_j'} =\left( \frac{{x^h_{j'}-\zeta^h_{j'}}}{{x^h_{j}-\zeta^h_{j}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sigma}} = \frac{p_j}{p_{j'}}
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{L}$ denotes the lagrangian. The constraint I used is: $\sum_{j=1}^{N} p_j x_j = w^h$.
Now, solving the expression above by $x^h_{j'}$ and plugging it into the constraint
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j \ne j'} p_j x^h_j + (p_j)^{\sigma} p^{1-\sigma}_{j'} (x^h_j - \zeta^h_j) +  p_{j'} \zeta^h_{j'}=w^h
\end{equation}
I'm not sure that what I'm doing is correct. If so, how should I continue?